# GraphicsExtension for Drawing?

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

Is there for System.Drawing an equalivant of GraphicsExtension?

Comment: It's an internal class to extend the System.Graphics class. Just wondering if there's a similar class for System.Drawing...

Comment: `System.Drawing` is a namespace, not a class. Neither is `System.Graphics`. And internal to what? Not the .NET framework, anyway.

Comment: @ErikHeemskerk, your correct, `System.Drawing` is indeed a namespace, miswritten myself here. 
I can't find any documentation about the `GraphicsExtension` *class* on MSDN (other then this: http://bit.ly/9DF1hz), but if you search around the web you find that it's used to extend the methods in the Graphics class. Just wondering if there's something I can do with the Drawing class (e.g. the Rectangle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, a little late, but I found out that extension methods where introduced in C# 3.0. They are possible for many class, not only bounded to the `Graphics` class.

More information can be found here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx
- http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3592216/Using-the-New-Extension-Methods-Feature-in-C-30.htm